# Parse a JSON array into a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(pump_array);
var name_array = [];
var data_array = [];
for(var i=0;i<jsonData.pumps.length;i++)
{
data_array.push(data_array, pump_array.pumps[i].volume);
name_array.push(name_array, pump_array.pumps[i].iName);}
```

this is my javascript code. I am trying to parse out specific pieces of the following json array in order to place it into a graph using chart.js

```
var pump_array = {
"pumps":[
    {
  "id": 1,
  "isPrimed":true,
  "iName": "Whiskey",
  "volume": 850,
  "debug": "Test"
    },

    {
  "id": 2,
  "isPrimed":true,
  "iName": "Vodka",
  "volume": 900,
  "debug": "Test"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to chart?  Can you describe what form you need your array to be?

Comment: How do you expect `pump_array` to be of any use when you've not assigned anything to it? Consider replacing `pump_array` with `jsonData.pumps`. or setting `pump_array = jsonData.pumps;`

Comment: `JSON.parse` is for use on strings, not arbitrary objects.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be several things wrong here.  First of all, you're calling `JSON.parse` on something that's not a string.  It's a full-fledged Javascript object.  There's no need to parse it; just use it.

Second of all, these two lines have an extra variable each:

```
data_array.push(data_array, pump_array.pumps[i].volume);
name_array.push(name_array, pump_array.pumps[i].iName);}
```

Presumably they should read:

```
data_array.push(pump_array.pumps[i].volume);
name_array.push(pump_array.pumps[i].iName);}
```

But even if you correct these problems, you still end up with a less-than-ideal data structure:

```
name_array; //=> ["Whiskey", "Vodka"]
data_array; //=> [850, 900]
```

Instead of a single, useful data structure, you end up with two different ones that are only useful via shared indices.

How about something like this instead?:

```
pump_array.pumps.reduce(function(soFar, pump) {
    soFar[pump.iName] = pump.volume; 
    return soFar;
}, {});
//=> {Whiskey: 850, Vodka: 900}
```

To my eyes, that's a much more useful data structure.